# Using shared_ptr as output parameter

Tags: c++, api, error-handling, shared-ptr

I'm working on a C++ API which exports several classes from a DLL.

A public class interface should follow the following conventions:

- All functions return an error code.
- Output parameters are used for additional return values.
- Pass by pointer is used for Output parameters.
- Pass by const reference is used for Input parameters (pass by value for primitive types).
- When the client should take ownership of output parameter `shared_ptr` is used, otherwise a normal pointer.

Example interface:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Object> ObjectPtr;

class APIClass
{
    ErrorCode SetSomething(int i);
    ErrorCode IsSomethingSet(bool* ask);
    ErrorCode DoSomething();
    ErrorCode GetSomething(ObjectPtr* outObj);
}
```

Example usage:

```
ErrorCode res;
ObjectPtr obj;
res = myApiClass->GetSomething(&obj);
```

GetSomething implementation:

```
ErrorCode APIClass::GetSomething(ObjectPtr* outObj)
{
   ObjectPtr temp(new Object(), CleanUpFunction<Object>);

   // Do something with object temp.
   ...

   *outObj= temp;

   return OK;
}
```

Is it save to use a shared_ptr in this way or are there possible issues I should be aware of?

Comment: Have you considered using [exceptions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html) instead of returning error codes?

Comment: Yes but I don't want to use exceptions because of the restrictions using them across DLL boundaries

Comment: Edited the question because it was too verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine, but I'd ask whether a shared pointer is really necessary in this case. Mostly because you can't release a pointer from a `shared_ptr` in any sane way... this can lead to problems later. And `shared_ptr` really means unspecified or shared ownership of the underlying resource.

I typically document the function and use something like:

```
// Caller must delete the outObj once done.
ErrorCode APIClass::GetSomething( Object* & outObj )
{
  // I use auto_ptr so I can release it later...
  // Mostly I hate auto_ptr, but for this its invaluable.

  auto_ptr<Object> obj( new Object );
  ...
  outObj = obj.release();
  return OK;
}
```

This way it is up to the client what they want to store the pointer into, and it is clear that ownership of the object passes to the caller.

Client code can then use an appropriate container.

```
Object * obj_raw;
ErrorCode ec = apiClass.GetSomething( obj_raw )
if( ec!=OK ) { .. do something with ec .. }
shared_ptr<Object> obj( obj_raw );
```

or

```
auto_ptr<Object> obj( obj_raw );
```

or

```
scoped_ptr<Object> obj( obj_raw);
```

etc.

Note that this can be made neater if you change your function definition to:

```
// Caller must delete the return value.
// On error, NULL is returned and e filled in appropriately.
Object* APIClass::GetSomething( ErrorCode & e )
{
   auto_ptr<Object> obj( new Object );
   ..
   e = OK;
   return obj.release();
}

//Now using it looks like this:
ErrorCode ec;
shared_ptr<Object> obj( apiObject.GetSomething(ec) ); 
if(!obj)
{
   .. do something with ec ..
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is the problem with passing pointers across DLL boundaries (at least on Windows), e.g. allocating memory in the DLL and deleting it on the client side . See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx. That's why I am using a custom deleter which is defined in the DLL (CleanUpFunction<Object>) when creating the shared_ptr.

Comment: But generally you think the solution should be fine as I understand? In which case might it be a problem to not able to release the pointer later or why do you would like to release it?

Comment: Also I was thinking about the alternative design similar to the one you mentioned with passing the error code as optional parameter like this: ObjectPtr APIClass::GetSomething( ErrorCode* e = nullptr). But could not decide yet which design is better.

Comment: @Hoschie0815 The reason you might want to release it later is to pass it to an interface that expects to take ownership of the object.

Comment: @Hoschie0815 `shared_ptr` doesn't save you from the memory allocation issue, as the shared_ptr constructor allocates a chunk (containing a reference count etc) and its destructor deallocates the chunk. If its getting created in the DLL and destroyed outside the DLL, you're back with exactly the same problem.